# Bajar y subir el scroll automáticamente en Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, scroll

Buen día, estoy buscando documentación para bajar y subir el scroll automáticamente en angular js 
ejemplo tengo un listado con unos pacientes y necesito que baje y suba el listado solo para que los pacientes puedan buscarse desde  un tV, estaba usando la funcion   window.scrollTop pero me genera error diciendo que no es una funcion valida

```
<button onClick="window.scrollTop()">Clic para desplazarse hacia abajo 100 pixeles</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiza puedas utilizar anclas HTML5 no es necesario usar javascript ni angular asi te puedes desplazar a donde le indiques el id, te dejo un ejemplo

```
<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><h1><a href="#ir-a-principiantes">Principiantes</a></h1></li>
      <li><h1><a href="#ir-a-intermedios">Intermedios</a></h1></li>
      <li><h1><a href="#ir-a-avanzados">Avanzados</a></h1></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div>
   <h1 id="ir-a-principiantes">Principiantes</h1>
   <p>Texto introducción</p>
</div>
<div>
   <h1 id="ir-a-intermedios">Intermedios</h1>
   <p>Texto desarrollo</p>
</div>
<div>
   <h1 id="ir-a-avanzados">Avanzados</h1>
   <p>Texto fin</p>
</div>
```